# Is $C^\infty([0,1]^n)$ a separable Frechet space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, separable-spaces

Gaussian Processes (GP) are widely viewed as practical ways to implement Gaussian Measures (GM) numerically. In fact, in many contexts it seems that to each GP corresponds a GM and vice versa, see, e.g.,
[this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2240205). The focus there is mainly on GP/M on infinite dimensional spaces. In particular, they consider the separable Frechet spaces $C(I),\,C^k(I),\,AC(I)$, where $I$ is a real interval. Separability is an important assumption that ensures the fact that

*The Borel sigma algebra on a Frechet space $X$ coincides with the smallest sigma algebra which makes continous linear functionals on $X$ measurable* (see top p.3 [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2240205))

Replacing the real interval with a bounded open set in $\mathbb R^n$ changes nothing in their approach. My question is whether the result holds also for $C^\infty$, let's say on the unit cube -- open or closed. I could not adjust the proof for $C^k$ (obviously), nor could I find a reference, despite scouring the internet.

Does anyone know the answer for the question in the title? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps provide a reference for $C^\infty([0,1]^n)$, since $[0,1]^n$ isn't an open set in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Consider the the same question either with $(0,1)^n$ or take the family of seminorms $p_\alpha(f)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]^n}|\partial^\alpha f(x)|$, where $\alpha$ is a multi index

Comment: My first thought would've been that $C^\infty[0,1]^n$ is separable by a $C^k$ version of Weierstrass' polynomial approximation. Is it not?

Comment: For example, what does $\partial^\alpha f(x)$ mean on a boundary point $x$ of $[0,1]^n$?  When we talk of $C^\infty\big((0,1)^n\big)$, we allow unbounded functions, and we have seminorms using compact subsets $K \subset (0,1)^n$.  [Shouldn't someone named Sobolev know that?]

Comment: @GEdgar For $Q\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ and $x\in Q$, you can define directional derivatives $D_rf(x)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0} (f(x+tr)-f(x))/t$ whenever $0$ is in the closure of $\{r\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}: x+tr\in Q\}$. For a cube, all directional derivatives make sense.

Comment: Ooops, not all directional derivatives exist for the cube, but **enough** directional derivatives exist.

Comment: I apologize to @Jose27 and Jochen because I did not find the argument using polynomial approximation. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $C^\infty([0,1]^n)$ is a very nice **nuclear** Fréchet space which, in particular, is separable.

The definition of differentiability is no problem since, at all points $x$ of the cube $Q=[0,1]^n$ and for each direction $r\in S^{n-1}$, either $x+tr\in Q$ for all small $t>0$ or $x-tr\in Q$ for all small $t>0$. **(As pointed out by GEdgar, this is nonsense. But the partial derivatives exist. In general, it is important that enough directional derivatives exist to define the Fréchet derivative uniquely.)**

The topology of $C^\infty(Q)$ is the topology of uniform convergence on $Q$ of all partial derivatives. That this topology is completely metrizable is a standard argument based on the fundamental theorem of calculus (for $f_n\to f$ such that $\partial_j f_n\to g_j$ uniformly, the limit $f$ is partially differentiable with $\partial_f=g$). Also nuclearity is, essentially, a consequence of the FTC, alternatively, one can use Arzelá-Ascoli to prove that $C^\infty(Q)$ is Fréchet-Schwartz which is enough for separability (but slightly weaker than nuclearity). You can also show directly that (restrictions to $Q$ of) polynomials are dense in $Q$, e.g., using Weierstrass's theorem as suggested in the comment of Jose27. As a reference I would recommend the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt.

A simple instance of Whitney's extension theorem implies that the restriction operator $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\to C^\infty(Q)$, $f\mapsto f|_Q$ is surjective and even has a continuous linear right inverse.

For general compact sets $Q$ there is a notion of *smooth functions on* $Q$ in terms of *Whitney jets*. The definition is somwhat elaborated but it turns out that the restriction operators from $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ to $C^\infty(Q)$ (which is usually denoted as $\mathscr E(Q)$) is surjective  but the existence of a continuous linear right inverse (an extension operator) is a notorously difficult question about the geoemtry of $Q$.

Comment: So, if $Q=[0,1]^2$ and $x$ is the origin $(0,0)$ and $r$ points into the second quadrant, then $x+tr$ and $x-tr$ are both outside $Q$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Ooops. Nevertheless, the partial derivatives both exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the nice answers and insights!!

Since the original question spawned a second question, I am writing an answer trying to address this secondary question:

I am sorry that @GEdgar struggled so much with the definition of $C^\infty([0,1]^n)$. For me $C^m(\bar\Omega)$ for open and bounded $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ is always given by restrictions of $C^m(\mathbb R^n)$ functions; here we can include $m=\infty$. Its Banach ($m<\infty$) or Frechet ($m=\infty$) space structure is given by the semi norms $p_\alpha(f)=\sup_{x\in \Omega}|\partial^\alpha F(x)| $ for $|\alpha|<m+1$, where $F\big |_\Omega=f$. There is no problem of well definedness because all extensions $F$ and their derivatives coincide in $\Omega$. It can thus be identified with a linear subspace of $C^m(\Omega)$. The completeness of $C^m(\bar\Omega)$ follows from the Whitney extension theorem.

It seems to me that one can also define
$$
C^\infty(\bar\Omega)=\{f\in C^\infty(\Omega)\colon \partial^\alpha f\text{ is uniformly continuous}\}
$$
and then the semi norms give the right topology.

Defining $C^\infty(K)$ for an arbitrary compact set $K$ requires more work because the well definedness of the seminorms of $f$ in terms of the extensions $F$ is no longer so clear. Then one needs to use an intrinsic definition as in the last paragraph of @Jochen's comprehensive answer.